# How to use custom managers in chain queries?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-managers

I made a custom manager that has to randomize my query:

```
class RandomManager(models.Manager):

    def randomize(self):        
        count = self.aggregate(count=Count('id'))['count']
        random_index = random.randint(0, count - 1)
        return self.all()[random_index]
```

When I use the method defined in my manager in the first place, it's works ok:

```
>>> PostPages.random_objects.randomize()
>>> <PostPages: post 3>
```

I need to randomize the already filtered query. When I tried to use the manager and the method in chain I got an error:

```
PostPages.random_objects.filter(image_gallary__isnull=False).randomize()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/i159/workspace/shivaroot/shivablog/<ipython-input-9-98f654c77896> in <module>()
----> 1 PostPages.random_objects.filter(image_gallary__isnull=False).randomize()

AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'randomize'
```

Result of filtering is not an instance of model class, but it's `django.db.models.query.QuerySet`, so that it does not have my manager and method, respectively. 
***Is there a way to use custom manager in chain query?***

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like this snippet provides a solution to your situation: [Custom managers with chainable filters](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/562/).

Comment: If you're using Django 1.7+, see the answer below, as the functionality comes out of the box.

Answer (score 33):

This is how you chain custom methods on custom manager ie: Post.objects.by_author(user=request.user).published()

```
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

class PostMixin(object):
    def by_author(self, user):
        return self.filter(user=user)

    def published(self):
        return self.filter(published__lte=datetime.now())

class PostQuerySet(QuerySet, PostMixin):
    pass

class PostManager(models.Manager, PostMixin):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return PostQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)
```

Comment: This is really neat. You have all your custom methods accessible within `Manager` and `Queryset` and they are all defined in one class. To push it even further, one could define decorator to make codebase smaller. Although, I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: very nice way to do it

Comment: +1 for the Django 1.7 way to do it, but shouldn't it be QuerySet.as_manager()?  This should be also marked as correct answer in my opinion..

Comment: Shouldn't the mixin classes be on the left of the base class when specifying inheritance?

Answer (score 16):

Just a code example using the new as_manager() method (see update information from @zzart.

```
class MyQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def randomize(self):        
        count = self.aggregate(count=Count('id'))['count']
        random_index = random.randint(0, count - 1)
        return self.all()[random_index]

class MyModel(models.Model):
    .....
    .....
    objects = MyQuerySet.as_manager()
    .....
    .....
```

And then you will be able to use something like this in your code:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(age__gt=16).randomize()
```

As you can see, the new as_manager() is really neat:)

Comment: Just used `.as_manager()` and verified this is the way to do it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have an existing `models.Manager` and you don't want to expose some of the manager method to a chainable queryset, you can use [`Manager.from_queryset(QuerySet)()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#from-queryset).

So, you could still place all your chainable queryset method inside the QuerySet and your manager method independently.

Example given in the official site.

> Snippet from  Django Docs

```
class BaseManager(models.Manager):
    # Available only on Manager.
    def manager_only_method(self):
        return

class CustomQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    # Available on both Manager and QuerySet.
    def manager_and_queryset_method(self):
        return

    # Available only on QuerySet.
    def _private_method(self):
        return

CustomManager = BaseManager.from_queryset(CustomQuerySet)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    objects = CustomManager()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like below which creates the custom QuerySet dynamically and allows us to 'transplant' our custom queries onto the returned QuerySet instance:

```
class OfferManager(models.Manager):
    """
    Additional methods / constants to Offer's objects manager
    """
    ### Model (db table) wide constants - we put these and 
    ### not in model definition to avoid circular imports.
    ### One can access these constants through like
    <foo>.objects.STATUS_DISABLED or ImageManager.STATUS_DISABLED

    STATUS_DISABLED = 0
    ...
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (STATUS_DISABLED, "Disabled"),
        (STATUS_ENABLED, "Enabled"),
        (STATUS_NEGOTIATED, "Negotiated"),
        (STATUS_ARCHIVED, "Archived"),
    )
    ...

    # we keep status and filters naming a little different as
    # it is not one-to-one mapping in all situations
    QUERYSET_PUBLIC_KWARGS = {'status__gte': STATUS_ENABLED}
    QUERYSET_ACTIVE_KWARGS = {'status': STATUS_ENABLED}

    def get_query_set(self):
        """ our customized method which transpalats manager methods
        as per get_query_set.<method_name> = <method> definitions """
        CustomizedQuerySet = QuerySet
        for name, function in self.get_query_set.__dict__.items():
            setattr(CustomizedQuerySet, name, function)
        return CustomizedQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def public(self):
        """ Returns all entries accessible through front end site"""
        return self.all().filter(**OfferManager.QUERYSET_PUBLIC_KWARGS)
    get_query_set.public = public # will tranplat the function onto the 
                                  # returned QuerySet instance which 
                                  # means 'self' changes depending on context.

    def active(self):
        """ returns offers that are open to negotiation """
        return self.public().filter(**OfferManager.QUERYSET_ACTIVE_KWARGS)
    get_query_set.active = active
    ...
```

More polished version of this method and django ticket here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20625.